# Changing the name of a value in a combobox

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, combobox

So I have this code:

```
    public void ChangeDefault()
    {
        string selectedPath = selectdirectories.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (selectedPath == "Data")
        {
            selectdirectories.ValueMember = "<Default>";
        }
    }
```

Im trying to change the name of a value in my combobox name selectdirectories, but it does not seem to be working. There are no errors it just doesnt work.

I also tried DisplayMember but that didnt work either.

Comment: How are you initially binding the values to `selecteddirectories`?  You may need to re-bind after you alter the `ValueMember`.

Comment: I use a foreach loop to go through a Directory and get the directories that begin with the word Data in them

Comment: well that code wont do what you've described either - it'll match only ones called 'Data'.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/5c588e980e5b92a44bc4 is my code on this form....I see what youre saying. Its hard for me to explain. I have a folder named Data, but I want it to appear as <Default> in the combobox. If a user clicks on it, I want the registry to be set to Data. Not <Default>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right the thing you want to do, then something like this should work:

```
selectdirectories.Items[selectdirectories.Items.IndexOf("Data")] = "<Default>";
```